# Deleting members / Changing Author of multiple entries

Tags: database, safecracker, plugin

I used zoo member/safecracker to allow registered members submit 1 entry (application form) a few months back. I now need to open this form back up for submissions again. I need to save the original submissions in the database but need to remove the registered members so they can submit again.

I believe that the author of the entries needs to be changed before the members are deleted.

Does anyone know of a plug-in to change the author of multiple entries (1000 aprox) or what syntax to use for the database query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your SQL query would look something like this:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_titles SET author_id = XX WHERE entry_id IN(34,278,45,91, [...]);
```

You'll want to run a [Recount Statistics](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/tools/data/recount_statistics.html) afterwards as well.

(If there was something common to all of these entries, you could possibly incorporate more into the query that would prevent you from having to have a comma-delimited list of all the entry_ids hard-coded.)

Comment: If you want to change the author of *all* entries in a channel you can use ... `WHERE channel_id = ID` (where ID is the id number of the channel to update).

Comment: Also, I *think* you only need to do the first UPDATE. I don't think the `exp_channel_data` table has an `author_id` field.

Comment: Totally correct Andrew, my bad - updated my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks Derek, and Andrew. From my (limited) understanding I need to run  `UPDATE exp_channel_titles SET author_id = XX WHERE entry_id IN(34,278,45,91, [...]);`     listing the entry_ids as the author_id is not available using `WHERE channel_id`. I think I'll do a backup first :)

Comment: What Andrew was saying is that *if* you want to change the author for *every entry* in this particular channel, you could use `WHERE channel_id = XX` *instead of* `WHERE entry_id IN([your comma-separated list of entry_ids])`.

Comment: That's great Derek. I'll be using Andrews solution as it would suit this purpose. Thanks for the follow up.

Comment: Micky - don't forget to mark accepted answers as "accepted" (with the checkmark icon).